# Transitive target_include_directories on OBJECT libraries

Tags: cmake

Here is snippet from make CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_library(foo-object OBJECT src/foo.cpp)
target_include_directories(foo-object PUBLIC include)
add_library(foo SHARED $<TARGET_OBJECTS:${PROJECT_NAME}-object>)
add_library(foo_static STATIC $<TARGET_OBJECTS:${PROJECT_NAME}-object>)
```

Now, this all works fine, both libraries are generated. However I have a problem when I try to use it:

```
add_executable(bar src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(bar foo)
```

Target `bar` doesn't compile, because include directories from foo-object are not propagated. If I add `target_include_directories` directly on `foo` as well, everything will compile fine.

How can I make both `foo` and `foo_static` automatically use (and forward to stuff depending on them) include directories from `foo-object`?

Comment: Good title - made a hard question easy to find.

Comment: There's now a nice clean way! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31290077/how-to-specify-imported-dependencies-of-object-library/51436025#51436025

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hm, at the moment I came up with following:

```
add_library(foo-object OBJECT src/foo.cpp)
target_include_directories(foo-object PUBLIC include)

get_property(object_include_dirs TARGET foo-object PROPERTY INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
get_property(object_link_libs TARGET foo-object PROPERTY LINK_LIBRARIES)

add_library(foo SHARED $<TARGET_OBJECTS:${PROJECT_NAME}-object>)
target_include_directories(foo PUBLIC ${object_include_dirs})
target_link_libraries(foo PUBLIC ${object_link_libs})

add_library(foo_static STATIC $<TARGET_OBJECTS:${PROJECT_NAME}-object>)
target_include_directories(foo_static PUBLIC ${object_include_dirs})
target_link_libraries(foo_static PUBLIC ${object_link_libs})
```

but come on, there must be better way :/

Comment: Just `target_link_libraries(foo PUBLIC foo-object)` isn't enough?

Comment: I will try that, I think it should work possibly? Thanks, I was pretty sure there must be smarted way :D

Comment: @wasthishelpful: good idea but not working: "Target "foo-object" of type OBJECT_LIBRARY may not be linked into another target.  One may link only to STATIC or SHARED libraries, or to executables with the ENABLE_EXPORTS property set."

Comment: So just `target_include_directories(foo PUBLIC ${object_include_dirs})` isn't enough? Maybe with the [generator expression](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) `$<TARGET_PROPERTY:tgt,prop>` to avoid the get line?

Comment: the generator expressions allows me to avoid get line, cool, thanks :)

Comment: Using `OBJECT` libraries ends up in a mess if using `install(EXPORT ...)`. From my latest experiences I do not recommend using `OBJECT` libraries at all, until CMake properly implements `target_link_libraries` support for them. Instead use a normal library (even if the physical file is not required in the project). Refer to the following issue on the offical CMake bug tracker for additional information: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/14778

Comment: target_include_directories(foo PUBLIC include) was all I needed (not sure what generator expression pulls the include dir "include" from foo-object)

Comment: target_include_directories(foo PUBLIC $<TARGET_PROPERTY:foo-object,INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>) is the version with generator expression

Answer (score 8):

It seems that transitive properties only work when targets are linked through a chain of `target_link_library` calls. In your case, you do not have such a link between `foo-object` and `foo`.

If you add a source file to `foo`, that one should also not be able to see the include directory from `foo-object`.

This might be an oversight in the design of `OBJECT` libraries, as it essentially breaks the transitive properties for those.

Answer (score 2):

On CMake <3.12, use the following:

```
add_library(foo SHARED $<TARGET_OBJECTS:${PROJECT_NAME}-object>)
target_include_directories(foo
    PRIVATE
    $<TARGET_PROPERTY:${PROJECT_NAME}-object,INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>)
```

On CMake >=3.12, take a look [at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31290077/how-to-specify-imported-dependencies-of-an-object-library/51436025#51436025) (thanks [@ian5v](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1234621/ian5v) for the suggestion)

---

How it works:

> [`target_include_directories(...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_include_directories.html)
>
> ...
>
> `PUBLIC` and `INTERFACE` items will populate the `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` property of `<target>`.

Therefore `${PROJECT_NAME}-object` has `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` set on it. We need to fetch this property and insert it into our own include path.

This looks like a job for ["generator expressions"](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html)!. In particular, `$<TARGET_PROPERTY:tgt,prop>` looks like it will come in handy here.

Our `tgt` will be `${PROJECT_NAME}-object`, and we're trying to extract all of the values of `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`, so `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` will be `prop`.

This comes out to `$<TARGET_PROPERTY:${PROJECT_NAME}-object,INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>`, which is exactly what we've used in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

For me something like the following seems to be working:

```
add_library(foo_objects OBJECT src/foo.cpp src/foo.hpp)
set_property(TARGET foo_objects PROPERTY POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)
target_include_directories(foo_objects PUBLIC
    "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:src>"
    "$<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>")

add_library(foo_shared SHARED)
add_library(foo_static STATIC)
target_link_libraries(foo_shared PUBLIC foo_objects)
target_link_libraries(foo_static PUBLIC foo_objects)
```