# Transitive dependencies and OBJECT libraries

Tags: cmake

A somewhat similar question was asked here, [Transitive target_include_directories on OBJECT libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38832528/transitive-target-include-directories-on-object-libraries), but there was no real solution.

If I have a project b that depends on a project a I can build them as follows

```
add_library(a OBJECT ${a_srcs})
add_library(b OBJECT ${b_srcs})
```

When I want to build an excutable using I them I can write

```
add_executable(p ${p_srcs} $<TARGET_OBJECTS:b> $<TARGET_OBJECTS:a>)
```

Is there any way to not have to specify `$<TARGET_OBJECTS:a>`? I assume this means telling CMake in some way that there is a dependency. If I was building SHARED libraries rather than OBJECT ones the b project would contain

```
target_link_libraries(b a)
```

which creates this dependency, but I can't find some equivalent way for OBJECT libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Insofar as I understand it, in the current setup, **no**.  The `add_executable` for target `p` can either

1. Link against some *library* (shared or static), or
2. Merge *object* sources into itself.

You have chosen (2).  The only other option I see here is create a third library `c` that merges in `a` and `b` into a full-blown library (see [`Usage` section at the bottom](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/Object_Library), which is likely where you were already looking).

When you do that, you could then `target_link_libraries(c)`.  The compiled `OBJECT`s cannot be linked against on their own.  You have to merge the sources into either an executable or a library for them to be used.

Your `add_executable` call could be thought of basically doing `add_executable(p ${p_srcs} ${a_srcs} ${b_srcs})`, only instead of compiling `a_srcs` and `b_srcs` (which has been done previously), just copy in the compiled objects instead of redoing the work.  That's a really simple / bad explanation, but that's the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I have found to do this is to wrap the `OBJECT` library in an `INTERFACE` library.

```
add_library(a-objects OBJECT ${a_srcs})
add_library(b-objects OBJECT ${b_srcs})

add_library(a INTERFACE)
add_library(b INTERFACE)

target_link_libraries(a INTERFACE a-objects)
target_link_libraries(b INTERFACE b-objects)

target_sources(a INTERFACE $<TARGET_OBJECTS:a-objects>)
target_sources(b INTERFACE $<TARGET_OBJECTS:b-objects>)
```

My rule is to use the `OBJECT` library to set requirements, but only ever link against the `INTERFACE` library.

```
target_link_libraries(b-objects INTERFACE a)
```

Setting it up this way should allow you to link against both libraries like this:

```
add_executable(p ${p_srcs})
target_link_libraries(p PRIVATE b)
```